PySpark - Select dataframe.select() only if all five mandatory columns exist
I have a dataframe in which I am only trying the parse the source files if all 5 mandatory columns(D1,D2,D3,D4,D5) exist. Currently, the problem is I am getting the attribute error when D4 or D5 does not exist. Can someone please guide me?
fp_wmuf_df = fp_wmuf_df.select(

   fp_wmuf_df.D1,
   fp_wmuf_df.D2,
   translate(result_dict)(fp_wmuf_df.D3).alias("D3"),
   regexp_replace(fp_wmuf_df.D4, "/", "-slash-").alias("D4"),
   date_format(to_timestamp(fp_wmuf_df.D5 / 1000), "yyyy-MM-dd       HH:mm:ss.SSSX").alias("D5"),
   lit("").alias("result"),
)

Tried a few solutions but nothing worked

Do you mean something like if ['D1', 'D2', 'D3', 'D4', 'D5'] <= df.fp_wmuf_df:   fp_wmuf_df.select(...)?  Otherwise, could you add sample data and expected output?
